# How can I filter This in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a Django project (like LMS) and I want to filter **Lectures** by **Subject** in the template, I do it once but now I forgot how to do it. How can I do this?!

I want to filter it by foreign-key **Subject** in **Lecture** 
Here is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.

class Subject(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    Test = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    Slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Slug = slugify(self.Title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title

class Lecture(models.Model):
    Subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Video = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    More_Info = models.TextField()
    Audio_Lecture = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Lecture_Files = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Sheet = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Slug = slugify(self.Title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Lecture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

and here is my **views.py**

```
from Diploma.models import Lecture, Subject
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def Diploma(request):
    return render(request, 'Diploma/diploma.html', context={
        'sub' : Subject.objects.all(),
    })

def Diploma_Subject(request, slug):
    subject_Lecture = Subject.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Diploma/subject.html', context={
        'subj' : subject_Lecture,
        'lect' : Lecture.objects.filter(I do not know what I should write here)
    })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter the `Lecture` model based on the `slug` parameter you have to do the following:

```
lecture = Lecture.objects.filter(Slug=slug).first()
if lecture is not None:
    # lecture.Subject, lecture.Title ...
```

Or if you want to filter based on the `slug` property in `Subject` model you can do the following:

```
lectures = Lecture.objects.filter(Subject__Slug=slug)
for lecture in lectures:
    # lecture.Subject, lecture.Title ...
empty:
    print('There are any lectures related')
```

There are many things to explain here but I tried to give you a minimal repoducible example so you can custom it to achieve your goal.

Feel free to leave a comment if you have an specific doubt about understanding it.

Comment: hello @allexiusw, thanks a lot it is working

Comment: @SamuelKamal you can mark this answer as correct if it resolved your question.